# How to use partial_sum with an output container of a different type?

Tags: c++, c++20, std, visual-c++-2022

I am looking into partial_sum in `<numeric>` & `<algorithm>` in C++ (C++20).
According to documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) it is possible to have an output iterator `OutputIt` of a type different from the input one `InputIt`.

Let me give an example. Lets say we have a class defined as

```
typedef struct score_card {
    std::string name;
    int score;

} score_card;
```

I want to accumilate the `int score` of a `vector<score_card>` into a `vector<int>`
The documentation hints that an output iterator can be different from the input iterator in the declaration below (C++20)

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt, class BinaryOperation >
constexpr OutputIt partial_sum( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first,
                                BinaryOperation op );
```

If I try to implement it as so:

```
void partial_sum_score()
{
    std::vector<score_card> data{
        {"Bob", 2},
        {"Mallory", 1},
        {"Alice", 2},
        {"carol", 0}
    };

    std::vector<int> data_partial_sum{
        0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    auto accumilate_scores = [](score_card first, score_card second) {return first.score + second.score; };

    std::partial_sum(data.begin(), data.end(), data_partial_sum.begin(), accumilate_scores);
}
```

That would throw this error (on Microsoft VS 2022)

```
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'score_card' to 'int'  ******* C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\numeric  253 
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) ******  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\numeric  260
```

That makes some sense, as the first output element is an int and the first input element is score_card. But the implementation of the function doesnt seem to reference the _OutIt type anywhere:
(from numeric header):

```
template <class _InIt, class _OutIt, class _BinOp>
_CONSTEXPR20 _OutIt partial_sum(const _InIt _First, const _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest, _BinOp _Reduce_op) {
    // compute partial noncommutative and nonassociative reductions into _Dest, using _Reduce_op
    _Adl_verify_range(_First, _Last);
    auto _UFirst      = _Get_unwrapped(_First);
    const auto _ULast = _Get_unwrapped(_Last);
    auto _UDest       = _Get_unwrapped_n(_Dest, _Idl_distance<_InIt>(_UFirst, _ULast));

    if (_UFirst != _ULast) {
        _Iter_value_t<_InIt> _Val(*_UFirst);
        for (;;) {
            *_UDest = _Val;
            ++_UDest;
            ++_UFirst;
            if (_UFirst == _ULast) {
                break;
            }
#if _HAS_CXX20
            _Val = _Reduce_op(_STD move(_Val), *_UFirst);
#else // ^^^ _HAS_CXX20 ^^^ // vvv !_HAS_CXX20 vvv
            _Val      = _Reduce_op(_Val, *_UFirst);
#endif // _HAS_CXX20
        }
    }

    _Seek_wrapped(_Dest, _UDest);
    return _Dest;
}
```

What am I missing? And is this even possible? If not, why is output iterator different from input iterator?
(optionally) how is the output destination size mismatch handled (if data_partial_sum is of size 1 for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output iterator can be a different *type* from the input iterator, but the constraint is that the input iterator's value type has to be writeable into the output iterator.

That is, if the input iterator is `I` and the output iterator is `O`, then in C++20 terms, this is the concept:

```cpp
template <typename I, typename O>
concept writable_into = input_iterator<I>
    && requires (iter_value_t<I> value, O out) {
           *out = value;
       };
```

Or, alternatively, `O` has to satisfy `std::output_iterator<std::iter_value_t<I>>`.

Or, alternatively alternatively, the underlying types here can't change. `partial_sum` takes a range of `T` and writes a range of `T`. It can't take a range of `T` and write a range of `U`.

---

What you're trying to do is take a range of `score_card` (side-note, why is this a `typedef`? Just `struct score_card { ... };` please, this isn't C) and produce a range of `int`. You can't do that with `partial_sum` because you can't change the type, you can only change which binary operation is invoked on the type (i.e. you can change from `+` to `*` to any other binary function, but it still has to operate on `score_card`).

Instead, you just want to operate on the scores. Which is:

```cpp
auto scores = data | std::views::transform(&score_card::score);
std::partial_sum(scores.begin(), scores.end(), data_partial_sum.begin());
```

Now these are all the same type. Ideally this would eventually become:

```cpp
std::ranges::partial_sum(scores, data_partial_sum.begin());
```

But we don't have a range version of this algorithm yet.

---

It's also a bit scary to use `data_partial_sum.begin()` as the output iterator, since if you don't size the vector correct up-front, you're just writing off the back in a way that you have no control over. So `std::back_inserter(data_partial_sum)` is usually better.

Comment: That was super helpful Thanks
You noticed my C background too. Occupational hazard of working with legacy C app
Your point regarding concepts is probably spot on. I am quite ignorant of ranges & concepts (on my list, getting there)
Your reply made me consider using transform_inclusive_scan as so
`auto transform_score = [] (score_card card) {return card.score; };
std::transform_inclusive_scan(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(data_partial_sum), std::plus{}, transform_score);
`
And thanks to point out back_inserter. I was concerned about this in my post didnt know this existed.